# .net Core web api/swashbuckle basepath and paths issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, .net-core

My .net core web API project includes 
`[Route("/api/v1/members")]` attribute for the controller
and `[HttpGet("{id}")]` for the method `GetMemberById`

The resulting swagger description generated by swashbuckle is as follows:

```
"basePath":"/","paths":{"/api/v1/members/{id}":{"get":{"tags":["Profiles"],"operationId":"ApiV1MembersByIdGet",
```

Client generators use this `"ApiV1MembersByIdGet"` as the method name and I would like it to be `"MembersGetById"`

I believe the swagger description should be as follows:

```
"basePath":"/api/v1","paths":{"/members/{id}":{"get":{"tags":["Profiles"],"operationId":"MemberByIdGet"
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Base path is where your application is, so it's correct, since you installed your application in `/` path. If you install your application in "example.com/MyApp", basePath would be `/MyApp` and relative path `api1/v1/members`